# How to get specific data using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

I am using HtmlAgilityPack for scrapping data. 
Here is the link that i am using to scrap data 
[This Link](http://www.shabdkosh.com/bn/translate/%E0%A6%A7%E0%A6%BE%E0%A6%B0%E0%A7%8D%E0%A6%AE%E0%A6%BF%E0%A6%95)
The structure is something like that

```
<div id="left">
  <h2>
   <i id="bn7483" class="fa fa-volume-up fa-lg in au" title="Speak!"/>
   <span class="in">(dhaarmika) </span>
   <div class="row">
    ...
```

I need two data from there one is "(dhaarmika)" and another is the id from that is "bn7483" using this code

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc2 = web2.Load("http://www.shabdkosh.com/bn/translate/ধার্মিক");
HtmlNodeCollection nodes = doc2.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@class='in']");
```

I was able to get the first one data that is "(dhaarmika)".

But i couldn't get the second data.

Could anyone tell me how to get the second data???

Comment: what is the second data? i see nothing useful in id=bn7483, but if you want to get an elment by id you use `//*[@id='bn7483']`

Comment: I want exactly the id number that is bn7483 @decoherence

Comment: something like `var id =doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//i[@id]").Attributes["id"].Value`?

Comment: This works fine but i have another question that is how i handle exception like what should i do if there is no such attribute or any other exception ?? @decoherence

Comment: simply use an if statement such as `var nodeWithId=doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//i[@id]");if(nodeWithId!=null){var id = nodeWithId.Attributes["id"].Value};`

Answer (score 1):

Another possible way is by selecting preceding sibling of the `<span>` you already found :

```
var doc2 = new HtmlWeb().Load("http://www.shabdkosh.com/bn/translate/ধার্মিক");
var span = doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//span[@class='in']");
var i = node.SelectSingleNode("preceding-sibling::i[@id]")
            .Attributes["id"]
            .Value;
```